# Scrapyd schedule details into database

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

Hi I am using Scrpayd to schedule my spiders. The problem is that i want to keep track of all the historic information about the jobs scheduled so far. But if the scrapyd server re-starts all the information will be deleted.

My question is is there any other way to store those values into a persistent storage like sql server?

or is there any other way to do that ?

Can any one help me ?

Thanks,

Comment: I know that scrapyd has sqlite support https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/master/scrapyd/sqlite.py or you can use this package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-dblite/0.2.5

Comment: @CristianOlaru I can store the items into SQL server. But my question is i want to store the schedule information and other details. Please check my question :)

Comment: @CristianOlaru i want to keep track of the schedule information and logs even after the restart of my scrapyd server

Comment: oh now I understand, so here is an idea: write a script to parse the log files and store that information into database. Make a cron job for that script, also in your scrapyd.init (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/master/debian/scrapyd.init) run that script before restart or stop

Comment: You can use 'close_spider' pipeline to make a callback after the spider finish its work and it will return you a spider object with all its data like starting , finishing time and the all its counters. REF : http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#close_spider

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a spider middleware is perfect to do this job.
You can save in a DB the stats and other desired info as soon as the spider finish its job.

here's a draft:

```
from scrapy import signals
import os

class UpdateStatsMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, crawler):
        self.crawler = crawler
        # register close_spider method as callback for the spider_closed signal
        crawler.signals.connect(self.close_spider, signals.spider_closed)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def get_jobid(self):
        """Gets jobid through scrapyd's SCRAPY_JOB env variable"""
        return os.environ['SCRAPY_JOB']

    def close_spider(self, spider, reason):
        # do your magic here...
        spider.log('Finishing spider with reason: %s' % reason)
        stats = self.crawler.stats.get_stats()
        jobid = self.get_jobid()
        self.update_job_stats(jobid, stats)

    def update_job_stats(self, jobid, stats):
        # do your magic here...
        pass
```

http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html